# Automatic Android video backup on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, video, android

How do I get my Android videos to backup automatically? Pictures work great, but I have to do the videos manually.

Comment: I came across this bug report today, about this very issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+bug/1168641 The more people subscribe to it, the more likely it will get noticed.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the app only supports auto-upload of photos. Once there is support in the REST API for resumable uploads (so large interrupted uploads don't start uploading from zero), the files app will add auto-upload video support.